# datatables - Table plug-in for jQuery

Tags: html, datatables, media-queries

i am using datatables plug-in and having trouble with printing table that have more then 8 columns, 8+ columns are not shown in.

- i am using the button 'print' of datatables

What can i do(is there any answer from the plug-in angle?)?
if no, how can i print a table with a lot of columns(from the CSS angle, font size and so)

this is the table declaration:

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dt-agents">
```

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code. The number of columns shouldn't be an issue, but there could be a number of things in the way you generate the table that is causing this.

Comment: @jonmrich I solved that with hiding specific column, `#table selector td:nth-child(1)`